# Contact Form Seven Giving success message but the email not received in gmail

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

This is my my website https://www.techsparks.co.in

When I click on the contact form 7 its saying that the email sent successfully but we are not receiving the email in my mail list.I am using the contact form 7 in WordPress for all the form.it was working but suddenly stopped.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens when Contact form 7 shows sent message successfully but not getting the mail.

First of all if you are working in local server then without SMTP mail will not send and will show CF7 error. and if your site is on live server then check if SMTP is enabled on your server or not. If SMTP is not set then enabled it.

Now check in CF7 form Mail tab. If is there show any error then fist solve it and check `From` email setting. Make sure there would be like this.

```
Your Site <wordpress@your-site.com>
```

Because sometimes it send mails in spam because of incorrect value. So there should be email address like this `wordpress@your-site.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the email setting in backend and make sure you have added the right email address in confirmation.

Second thing is that if you have configure the smtp in your website. In this case your all emails will be redirect on smpt configure email.